# Reason for removal of a post

Tags: support

My posting of  "Frequency and elements of the Lord's Supper" was removed. Is it possible for me to find out why? Is there a way for me to see the posting? If so, how? Would the reason for its removal be there, assuming I can get there?

Answer (score 2):

It wasn't your answer per se, in this case the question was removed. It had been closed for some time, was not getting edited to be openable and the OP requested that it be removed.

Even if they tau not requested it, that is what would have happened anyway sooner or later. You can basically expect anything that is closed (exempt duplicates) and not worked on to find the dust bin eventually.

- Don't waste time answering questions that have obvious  problems. If you recognize they are likely to run afoul of our guidelines, fix them first then dig in to answering.
- If you run across something that gets closed and you think you know a way to fix it, do so. Not everything is worth salvaging or even possible to save but don't assume even good content will just hang around is limbo under a classed question.

Normally you would be able to see your own posts if they are deleted along with any comments that were left on them. Since it was not your post that was removed that does not apply but let me drop [a copy on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Cr40R4gC) in case you want to archive or reuse your own work.

**Edit:** Apparently this isn't the one I had in mind from yesterday that the OP requested deletion on, but it was off topic and the OP had commented with a question about whether it should be deleted.

Comment: OK. Gotcha. Thanks for the information. Don